# Unknown Math symbol (Calligraphic I in Statistics)

Tags: statistics, average

I came across a symbol I cannot figure out the meaning of. 
I found it in the LaTeX chart as a calligraphic I.

[This is the symbol in an equation for a bin weight in an RBF kernel circular local averaging method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW82Y.png)

d is the distance from the mean and k is the kernel (weighting width).

Comment: It is likely the *INDICATOR FUNCTION*, which yields a $1$ if its logical argument is "TRUE" and $0$ otherwise.  Make sense?

Comment: This could be the [Fisher Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information)

Comment: @K.defaoite Sorry, correction: This is likely NOT the Fisher Information but do note that the Fisher Information is also another common use of the calligraphic I.

Comment: How would Fisher information have an argument such as $d \leq |k|$?

Answer (score 1):

It is the Indicator function. More about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function